# Why can't rename file?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My code rename file in vb.Net:

```
Dim strFilename ="D:\2014\RF見本_P330_115%11.ai"
Dim newfile="D:\2014\RF見本_P330_115_11.ai"
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(strFilename , newfile)
```

But it occur error: `Unable to find the specified file.`
Why? How can rename this file?
Thanks all.

Comment: Does the file exist at that path?

Comment: Is that the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

`My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile` cannot be used to move a file to a new location.  To enforce this, the new name parameter cannot contain path information and cannot end in a `\`.  If the `file` parameter exists, then as you have it now you should get an`ArgumentException` with a message of:

> Argument 'newName' must be a name, and not a relative or absolute path

To fix this, you simply do not include the path in your `newFile` parameter:

```
Dim strFilename ="D:\2014\RF見本_P330_115%11.ai"
Dim newfile="RF見本_P330_115_11.ai"
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(strFilename , newfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to other things than the language/instruction. I created the same structure here and the copy was performed normally.

Check if the file has some special settings (like READONLY, PROTECTED and so forth) and if you HAVE the priviledges to access it and its folder.

I´m using:  VS2013, .NET Framework 4.0, Windows 8.1